# Bootstrap navbar overlapping body content

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, nav

I am having some issues with my Bootstrap navbar.

1. I have a lot of tabs in the navbar so the header gets on separate line and the tabs get on 2nd line which doesn't look good.
2. because navbar takes 2 line so it hides some content on my page, for example there is a heading above line "Please select cluster avg file...." in the attached image but you cant see it because navbar is overlapping and hiding it.
3. How can I fix this issue? I want the navbar to show only limited tabs , as possible in one line of navbar and hide other in the hamburger menu. So that it doesn't hide my body content and looks good as well.

P.S: these problem don't occur when I resize window to mobile view, because hamburger menu appears.

**Full Window**

[image]

**Mobile View**

[image]

and the code for navbar is default with ASP.NET Core web application only thing I changed was its theme to "inverse"

**Here's the code**

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" class="navbar-brand">ChromSACT</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" class="aa"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" style="margin-right:6px;"></span>Home</a></li>
                <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Cell">Input</a></li>
                <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="CellResult">Marks</a></li>
                <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="CellResultRegions">Regions</a></li>
                <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="ClusterBits">Cluster Bits</a></li>
                <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="RegionsMatrix">Regions Matrix</a></li>
                <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="MarksMatrix">Marks Matrix</a></li>
                <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Compare">Compare</a></li>
                <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="About"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-alert" style="margin-right:6px;"></span>About</a></li>
                <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Contact"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" style="margin-right:6px;"></span>Contact</a></li>
                <li><button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="btn navbar-btn btn-group-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" style="margin-right:6px;"></span>Instructions</button></li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container body-content" >
    @RenderBody()
    <hr />
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; 2016 - ChromSACT</p>
    </footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Acoording to bootstrap `navbar-fixed-top` docs:
###Body padding required

> The fixed navbar will overlay your other content, unless you add
> padding to the top of the `<body>`. Try out your own values or use our
> snippet below. Tip: By default, the navbar is 50px high.

```
body { padding-top: 70px; }
```

> Make sure to include this after the core Bootstrap CSS.

I think if it takes two lines on non-mobile viewport, you can set

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    body { padding-top: 100px; }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot media screen solution totally worked for me :)

Comment: Can you give an example of why the media solution is needed? I can't find a case where padding-top doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I work on a lot of different bootstrap sites with different themes and styling. Keeping the navbar padding right when changing styling to meet customer requests was a pain. I came up with this solution for Bootstrap 4. You would put this in a scss file after you have imported your theme and bootstrap.

```
body {
    padding-top: $navbar-padding-y + $nav-link-height + $navbar-padding-y;
}
```